# How to terminate an app after pressing any key and it will return to the Menu?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

How do I create a batch file that allows the user to select an app to be run then it will prompt "Press any key to continue", after pressing any key the selected appl will be terminated and will return to the Menu?

```
@echo off
title MENU
:menu
cls
echo.
echo SELECT APPLICATION YOU WANT TO RUN:
echo ===================================
echo.
echo 1. Google Chrome
echo 2. APP 2
echo 3. EXIT
echo.
echo ===================================
echo.

set /p web= Enter Number of Choice:

if "%web%"=="1" start chrome.exe (pause)
if "%web%=='2' start app2.exe (pause)
if "%web%"=='3' exit

goto menu

pause
```

Comment: Place the `PAUSE` statement above the `GOTO menu` statement...

Comment: there's a PAUSE already after executing the app. What i need now is i don't know how to terminate it after pressing any key

Comment: read `taskkill /?`, especially the `/IM` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
if "%web%"=="1" start chrome.exe & pause & taskkill /IM chrome.exe
...
```

Comment: thanks it worked! i added " & pause & goto menu " at the end ! tysm

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE MENU
:menu
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO SELECT APPLICATION YOU WANT TO RUN:
ECHO ===================================
ECHO.
ECHO 1. Google Chrome
ECHO 2. APP 2
ECHO 3. EXIT
ECHO.
ECHO ===================================
ECHO.

SET /p web= Enter Number of Choice:

IF "%web%" EQU "1" (
  START chrome.exe
) ELSE IF "%web% EQU "2" (
  START app2.exe
) ELSE IF "%web%" NEQ "3" GOTO menu

PAUSE
```

Comment: it didn't work for me but i appreciate your answer so much. Thanks for helping a noob out, tho!